# Replace nested loops in r that count rows meeting multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, performance, for-loop, nested-loops

I use more nested loops than I should, but am now looking to create more efficient code to share with colleagues, especially now that we are using larger datasets.

A common operation I do is that I look at each row, I

1. count how many rows from that group are within a certain timeframe of the row I'm focusing on,
2. how many rows in that timeframe (and group) meet a certain criteria, and
3. then use that ratio to assign a category.

I am struggling figuring out how to do tasks 1) and 2) in dplyr or in a vectorized manner.

I have attched a somewhat simplified version of a nested loop that I'm using. In this specific example, I am 1) going row by row to see how many measurements were within the past 100 seconds from that specific beaver, 2) seeing in how many of those row the temperature was greater than the median, and 3) assigning a category based on that.

```
#Creating an example dataframe with different groups (beavers) and times.
beaver_data <-  bind_rows( 
  beaver1 %>% mutate(beaver = "1"),
  beaver2 %>% mutate(beaver = "2")
) %>%
  filter(!(beaver == "1" & day == 347)) %>% #Removing the 2nd day from each beaver for simplicity.
  filter(!(beaver == "2" & day == 308))

beaver_data$class <- NA # This is what I would like to assign.

for(i in 1:nrow(beaver_data)){
        beaver_data_loop <- beaver_data %>% 
          filter(beaver == beaver_data$beaver[i]) %>% #Only selecting data from that beaver
          filter(between(time, beaver_data$time[i] - 100, beaver_data$time[i])) #Only counting rows within 100 seconds of that one.
        
        ratio_pass_offset_loop <-  sum(beaver_data_loop$temp > 37)/nrow(beaver_data_loop) #Finding what ratio of samples in that time period are above the median.
          
          if(ratio_pass_offset_loop < 0.5){ #If less than half are above the median, then it's low.
            beaver_data$class[i] <- "Low"
          } else if(ratio_pass_offset_loop < 1){ #If more than half but less than all are are above the median, medium.
            beaver_data$class[i] <- "Medium"
          } else { #Otherwise, assign it as high.
            beaver_data$class[i] <- "High" 
          }
}
```

I also had some success running task 1) in dplyr, but I could not get it to go the next step and count how many were also above the median.

```
beaver_data %>%
  group_by(beaver) %>%
  mutate( 
    CountWithin100Seconds = rowSums(
      sapply(time, function(x) {
        time - x >= 0 & time - x <= 100
      })
    ))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Stephen Hilton! This is a good first question, but it's going to be very difficult to give you working code without having sample data. Please [edit] your question to provide sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))` into a [code block]), and intended output given that input. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. Thanks!

Comment: Some comments though in general: This seems like it could be an inequality join (using `dplyr::join_by`, perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/q/76296316/3358272). Your `class[i] <- ...` assignment is almost certainly better done with `case_when` (not `if`/`else` statements), and doing it on the _whole ungrouped frame_ will be much better than row-by-row.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Rookie question, but if I'm using built-in datasets (beaver1 and beaver2), do I put something like head() in the code to make it more clear, or a commented-out version of the output dataframe?

Comment: I suggest  just specifying it is built-in (and which package, if a non-base package dataset), such as `datasets::beavers` or `MASS::beav1`. I cannot find a `beaver1` in my local set of packages, reinforcing the suggestion for clarity. My personal opinion: even if it is not in a package you are actively using, even if it is a non-base package, I and many others are perfectly able to extract data from a package regardless of whether the package is installed on my system. (For instance, I can get `.rda` files from `https://github.com/cran/dplyr/tree/master/data` without `dplyr` installed.)

Comment: okay, on further research, I now see that `datasets::beavers` is really `beaver1` and `2`, my bad. In my experience it is not frequently used in questions on SO, and I've never used them, so I did not recognize them. I suggest you can start your code block with `data("beavers", package="datasets") # beaver1, beaver2` for absolutely clarity on where the data comes from, that way under-informed people like me can get past the first hurdle :-)

Comment: That makes sense! It took me a while to find built-in data sets similar enough (some sort of time series, different groups), so it's pretty far down the list. But yeah that makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one implementation:

```r
beaver_data %>%
  mutate(
    ratio = sapply(time, function(time1) {
      ind <- between(time, time1 - 100, time1 - 1e-9)
      sum(temp[ind] > 37) / sum(ind)
    }),
  ratio = coalesce(ratio, 0),
  class = cut(ratio, c(-Inf, 0.5, 1, Inf),
              labels = c("Low", "Medium", "High")),
  .by = beaver)
#     day time  temp activ beaver   ratio  class
# 1   346  840 36.33     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 2   346  850 36.34     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 3   346  900 36.35     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 4   346  910 36.42     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 5   346  920 36.55     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 6   346  930 36.69     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 7   346  940 36.71     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 8   346  950 36.75     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 9   346 1000 36.81     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 10  346 1010 36.88     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 11  346 1020 36.89     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 12  346 1030 36.91     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 13  346 1040 36.85     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 14  346 1050 36.89     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 15  346 1100 36.89     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 16  346 1110 36.67     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 17  346 1120 36.50     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 18  346 1130 36.74     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 19  346 1140 36.77     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 20  346 1150 36.76     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 21  346 1200 36.78     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 22  346 1210 36.82     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 23  346 1220 36.89     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 24  346 1230 36.99     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 25  346 1240 36.92     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 26  346 1250 36.99     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 27  346 1300 36.89     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 28  346 1310 36.94     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 29  346 1320 36.92     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 30  346 1330 36.97     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 31  346 1340 36.91     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 32  346 1350 36.79     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 33  346 1400 36.77     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 34  346 1410 36.69     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 35  346 1420 36.62     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 36  346 1430 36.54     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 37  346 1440 36.55     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 38  346 1450 36.67     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 39  346 1500 36.69     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 40  346 1510 36.62     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 41  346 1520 36.64     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 42  346 1530 36.59     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 43  346 1540 36.65     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 44  346 1550 36.75     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 45  346 1600 36.80     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 46  346 1610 36.81     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 47  346 1620 36.87     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 48  346 1630 36.87     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 49  346 1640 36.89     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 50  346 1650 36.94     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 51  346 1700 36.98     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 52  346 1710 36.95     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 53  346 1720 37.00     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 54  346 1730 37.07     1      1 0.00000    Low
# 55  346 1740 37.05     0      1 0.16667    Low
# 56  346 1750 37.00     0      1 0.33333    Low
# 57  346 1800 36.95     0      1 0.33333    Low
# 58  346 1810 37.00     0      1 0.33333    Low
# 59  346 1820 36.94     0      1 0.33333    Low
# 60  346 1830 36.88     0      1 0.33333    Low
# 61  346 1840 36.93     0      1 0.16667    Low
# 62  346 1850 36.98     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 63  346 1900 36.97     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 64  346 1910 36.85     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 65  346 1920 36.92     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 66  346 1930 36.99     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 67  346 1940 37.01     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 68  346 1950 37.10     1      1 0.16667    Low
# 69  346 2000 37.09     0      1 0.33333    Low
# 70  346 2010 37.02     0      1 0.50000    Low
# 71  346 2020 36.96     0      1 0.66667 Medium
# 72  346 2030 36.84     0      1 0.66667 Medium
# 73  346 2040 36.87     0      1 0.66667 Medium
# 74  346 2050 36.85     0      1 0.50000    Low
# 75  346 2100 36.85     0      1 0.33333    Low
# 76  346 2110 36.87     0      1 0.16667    Low
# 77  346 2120 36.89     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 78  346 2130 36.86     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 79  346 2140 36.91     0      1 0.00000    Low
# 80  346 2150 37.53     1      1 0.00000    Low
# 81  346 2200 37.23     0      1 0.16667    Low
# 82  346 2210 37.20     0      1 0.33333    Low
# 83  346 2230 37.25     1      1 0.60000 Medium
# 84  346 2240 37.20     0      1 0.80000 Medium
# 85  346 2250 37.21     0      1 1.00000 Medium
# 86  346 2300 37.24     1      1 1.00000 Medium
# 87  346 2310 37.10     0      1 1.00000 Medium
# 88  346 2320 37.20     0      1 1.00000 Medium
# 89  346 2330 37.18     0      1 1.00000 Medium
# 90  346 2340 36.93     0      1 1.00000 Medium
# 91  346 2350 36.83     0      1 0.83333 Medium
# 92  307  930 36.58     0      2 0.00000    Low
# 93  307  940 36.73     0      2 0.00000    Low
# 94  307  950 36.93     0      2 0.00000    Low
# 95  307 1000 37.15     0      2 0.00000    Low
# 96  307 1010 37.23     0      2 0.25000    Low
# 97  307 1020 37.24     0      2 0.40000    Low
# 98  307 1030 37.24     0      2 0.50000    Low
# 99  307 1040 36.90     0      2 0.66667 Medium
# 100 307 1050 36.95     0      2 0.66667 Medium
# 101 307 1100 36.89     0      2 0.66667 Medium
# 102 307 1110 36.95     0      2 0.50000    Low
# 103 307 1120 37.00     0      2 0.33333    Low
# 104 307 1130 36.90     0      2 0.16667    Low
# 105 307 1140 36.99     0      2 0.00000    Low
# 106 307 1150 36.99     0      2 0.00000    Low
# 107 307 1200 37.01     0      2 0.00000    Low
# 108 307 1210 37.04     0      2 0.16667    Low
# 109 307 1220 37.04     0      2 0.33333    Low
# 110 307 1230 37.14     0      2 0.50000    Low
# 111 307 1240 37.07     0      2 0.66667 Medium
# 112 307 1250 36.98     0      2 0.83333 Medium
# 113 307 1300 37.01     0      2 0.83333 Medium
# 114 307 1310 36.97     0      2 0.83333 Medium
# 115 307 1320 36.97     0      2 0.66667 Medium
# 116 307 1330 37.12     0      2 0.50000    Low
# 117 307 1340 37.13     0      2 0.50000    Low
# 118 307 1350 37.14     0      2 0.50000    Low
# 119 307 1400 37.15     0      2 0.66667 Medium
# 120 307 1410 37.17     0      2 0.66667 Medium
# 121 307 1420 37.12     0      2 0.83333 Medium
# 122 307 1430 37.12     0      2 1.00000 Medium
# 123 307 1440 37.17     0      2 1.00000 Medium
# 124 307 1450 37.28     0      2 1.00000 Medium
# 125 307 1500 37.28     0      2 1.00000 Medium
# 126 307 1510 37.44     0      2 1.00000 Medium
# 127 307 1520 37.51     0      2 1.00000 Medium
# 128 307 1530 37.64     0      2 1.00000 Medium
# 129 307 1540 37.51     0      2 1.00000 Medium
# 130 307 1550 37.98     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 131 307 1600 38.02     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 132 307 1610 38.00     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 133 307 1620 38.24     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 134 307 1630 38.10     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 135 307 1640 38.24     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 136 307 1650 38.11     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 137 307 1700 38.02     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 138 307 1710 38.11     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 139 307 1720 38.01     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 140 307 1730 37.91     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 141 307 1740 37.96     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 142 307 1750 38.03     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 143 307 1800 38.17     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 144 307 1810 38.19     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 145 307 1820 38.18     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 146 307 1830 38.15     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 147 307 1840 38.04     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 148 307 1850 37.96     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 149 307 1900 37.84     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 150 307 1910 37.83     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 151 307 1920 37.84     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 152 307 1930 37.74     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 153 307 1940 37.76     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 154 307 1950 37.76     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 155 307 2000 37.64     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 156 307 2010 37.63     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 157 307 2020 38.06     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 158 307 2030 38.19     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 159 307 2040 38.35     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 160 307 2050 38.25     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 161 307 2100 37.86     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 162 307 2110 37.95     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 163 307 2120 37.95     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 164 307 2130 37.76     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 165 307 2140 37.60     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 166 307 2150 37.89     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 167 307 2200 37.86     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 168 307 2210 37.71     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 169 307 2220 37.78     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 170 307 2230 37.82     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 171 307 2240 37.76     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 172 307 2250 37.81     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 173 307 2300 37.84     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 174 307 2310 38.01     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 175 307 2320 38.10     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 176 307 2330 38.15     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 177 307 2340 37.92     1      2 1.00000 Medium
# 178 307 2350 37.64     1      2 1.00000 Medium
```

Notes:

- `class` here is a `factor`, whose order will be honored (using `sort`, `arrange`, etc) where it matters, including `dplyr` and `ggplot2`. If you need strict strings, then `as.character(..)`.
- The `sapply` anon-func first finds which rows (within the group) are in the specified time frame, and then conditionally sums the matching `temp`s of those rows. Realize that `time` is the whole vector of `time` for that group, and `time1` is just one row's value.
- I subtracted `1e-9` from `time1` for the upper value of the group since I don't want to match *this row* when summing and counting. If you want to include this row in the calculations, just remove this subtraction.

Comment: Thanks so much, that did what I was looking for! 

I don't use apply or functions in dplyr often, so I was wondering a few things. Could these functions be created outside of dplyr, and then called in dplyr? For my actual dataset, these functions would be done on a few different columns, and I figure that would make less busy code. Also, how does it know that time1 is the time for that row?

Comment: Sure, you can define something like `myfun <- function(time) sapply(time, function(time1) {...})` and then call `mutate(across(c(col1, col2, col3), ~ myfun(.)))` or similar, Is that what you meant?